# tailwindcss Dropdown Width by Selected Content

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am using tailwindcss.

How do I make the dropdown width according to the selected content.

```
        <div class="flex-none w-[120px] h-[55px]">
          <select class="h-[45px] w-full">
            <option selected="selected" value="1">All Departments</option>
            <option value="1">Volvo Volvo Volvo Volvo </option>
            <option value="2">Saab Saab Saab</option>
            <option value="3">Opel Opel </option>
            <option value="4">Audi</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the width with js. I don't see any other option.
This works really good:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#resizingSelectTag').change(function(){
    $("#widthTempOption").html($('#resizingSelectTag option:selected').text());
    $(this).width($("#selectTagWidth").width());  
 });
});
```

```css
#resizingSelectTag {
 width: 50px;
} 
 
#selectTagWidth{
 display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="resizingSelectTag">
  <option>All</option>
  <option>Lorem Ipsum</option>
  <option>Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.</option>
</select>

<select id="selectTagWidth">
 <option id="widthTempOption"></option>
</select>
```

Original Post from here: https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/auto-resize-select-tag-element-width-according-to-option/